# CodeIgniter does not autoload my core extension

Tags: php, codeigniter

As I am very pleased of the command `show_404()` which you can call everywhere to show a 404-Error-Page, I did want to implement a `show_403()` for requests without permissions.

I created the file `application/core/MY_Exceptions.php` and added the following code:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Exceptions extends CI_Exceptions {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function show_403($page = '', $log_error = TRUE)
    {
        //do some stuff
        echo "test";
    }
}
```

Then I'll call it in a controller `application/controllers/Welcome.php` like this:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        // show_404();  // <-- this works!
        show_403();     // <-- this works not!
    }
}
```

and I keep getting the following error in the browser, when I access the controllers index method:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function show_403()
```

As you may have noticed I even tested this on a vanilla installation of CodeIgniter, so you should be able to reproduce this error with just these two files.

I know that I could load the extension manually, but that has not the elegance of using `show_403()` wherever and whenever I want...

Routing is set up correctly, CodeIgniter is version 3.0.3, PHP is version 5.6.12., filesystem permissions to `application/core/MY_Exceptions.php` have even been set to 777 for debugging purposes.

Comment: check the first part of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your exception class is not loaded, so its giving that error.

Load your class like this

```
 $excep = load_class('Exceptions', 'core', $this->config->item('subclass_prefix'));
  echo $excep->show_403();// will echo test
```

One more suggesion is to use `helpers` for this,

Add your code in `application/helpers` with file name `error_helper`

```
public function show_403($page = '', $log_error = TRUE)
{
    //do some stuff
    echo "test";
}
```

Calling your function

```
$this->load->helper('error_helper');
echo show_403();
```

Comment: As I stated, "I know that I could load the extension manually". So is my expectation wrong, that MY_-Extensions are all loaded automatically? (thats for example the case with libraries!)